# Adding external library (Gurobi) to Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors, libraries, gurobi

I would like to use Gurobi in a C++ project I have in Eclipse. I tried multiple manuals/tutorials (including [THIS](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013194392-How-do-I-configure-a-new-Gurobi-C-project-with-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2017-) on how to do the same in Visual Studio) to add the hook up the Gurobi files with Eclipse/GCC, but I just couldn't make it work. I feel like I don't understand enough how these things should work in the first place.

In my Gurobi folder I have 3 folders, that in my opinion are important: `include` (with .h files), `lib` (with .lib files and NO .so or .a files) and `src` (with .cpp & .h files).

`include`: I added the path to this folder to ***C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths***, I guess this is for the compiler to see the .h files. I also added it to ***C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> Include directories***, I guess this is for the linker to see the .h files.

`lib`: I first added the folder path to ***C/C++ Build -> Settings -> MinGW C++ Linker -> Libraries -> Libraries (-l)***, however after searching online it seems to me this option only works for libraries with standard names and extensions. It also gave me the error `ld.exe: cannot find -lc:/gurobi900/win64/lib/`, so I deleted it and added the two .lib file paths separately to ***Miscellanous -> Other objects***.

I got to the point where `#include "gurobi_c++.h"` works, however, already Eclipse underlines a line where I am defining a GRBEnv() object, that is declared in `include/gurobi_c++.h`, but defined in `src/cpp/Env.cpp`. Also if I try to compile, I get `undefined reference` errors. This means neither the Linker nor the Compiler can see the definition of GRBEnv().

Is there a way to tell the linker/compiler where the .cpp files are? Is it happening automatically, based on the path of the `include` folder? Am I supposed to link the .lib or the .cpp files?

I would greatly appreciate even if someone just pointed out mistakes in my understanding.